# Extendscript current script path

Tags: extendscript

I want to get the absolute folder path of current running Extendscript.

i.e `__DIR__` in php (or) `__dirname` in nodejs. Equivalent in Extendscript.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found it myself, it is `$.fileName`

For the folder name, it is `(new File($.fileName)).parent`

Comment: FYI (if anybody is following), the folder path is returned *without* any trailing backslach, and it is already in extendscript format, for example: `/c/some%20folde%20with%spaces/some/folder`  -but the script likes this.

Comment: Might I clarify: `$.fileName` returns the absolute path to the **current executing script**, not the opened file (e.g. the .ai file you're editing in Illustrator).

Comment: At least in Illustrator, this only works when you open the script in ExtendScript, and execute it. It doesn't work when you open it directly.

Comment: Mind you, while `$.fileName` works fine in the context of "pure" scripting execution, it may return garbage (like a random integer) if you evaluate in the context of an HTML Panel in some Adobe applications such as Photoshop. In that case, if you need to get the absolute path of a JSX, you may want to use `CSInterface.prototype.getSystemPath()`

Comment: var scriptFolder = (new File($.fileName)).parent.fsName;

Answer (score 5):

[I wrote an article about this you may find helpful](http://armand.eu/blog/manage-paths-in-adobe-extend-script/), :)

essentially:

```js
var myPath = (app.activeDocument.fullName.parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');
var myScriptPath = (File(app.activeScript.fullName).parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');

alert('Document path is: ' + myPath + ' , and script path is: ' + myScriptPath);
```

mim,

Answer (score 3):

```
File($.fileName).path;
```

Seems to do the job nowadays

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reference files relative to the active document you can use `app.activeDocument.filePath`.

Comment: Note this is specific to Photoshop.  $.filename works across all apps.

Comment: `app.activeDocument` ≠ `app.activeScript`

Answer (score -1):

`app.activeScript.parent` should do the trick - note that if you use a windows file link, you get the *actual* script location, not the one of the .lnk-file.

Comment: FYI this is invalid for extendscript in After Effects.

Comment: Same for Photoshop